# Unobserve state variable in Vuex Store

Tags: vuejs2, observable, vuex

I've got a setup with Vue and Vuex (Store) in Typescript. State consists of two fields: a very complicated legacy object `data` and one simple --- `number`, e.g.,

```
Vue.use(Vuex);
const Store = new Vuex.Store<{ data: Data, n: number }>({
    state: {
        data: new Data(...),
        n: 1
    },
    mutations: {
        ...
    }
}
```

Both `data` and `n` can be updated in the mutations. By default, whatever is in the state gets to be observable and changes in any of state's fields trigger notifications to dependent methods, fields, etc.

I do not want `data` to be observable, any change to it via mutations should not trigger anything. How would I achieve this?

I see three options:

1. Unobserve `data` in Vuex via some workaround (I have no idea which)
2. Use Vuez, an alternative to Vuex whcih directly allows to state what must be observable, everything else is not observed (I have no experience with it)
3. Something else.

I'd be happy to learn about options 1 and 3.